# Error report - ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Tags: ora-00900

I am new to oracle, I am trying to grant the roles to the users via a procedure. I am receiving the following error. can someone please help me with this?

```
declare stmnt2 varchar(10000);
p_user_name varchar2(20);
v_role_name varchar2(20);
begin 
v_role_name := 'ROLE';
p_user_name := 'TOM';
stmnt2 := 'grant '||v_role_name||' to '
                           ||v_user_name||'; '
                           ||' grant connect to '
                           ||v_user_name ;  
execute immediate stmnt2;
end;
/

Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 10
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"

Thank you
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have spaces in your statement:

```
stmnt2 := 'grant '||v_role_name||' to '||p_user_name;
```

This must work better.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked but now I have the issue with the below statement: stmnt2 := 'grant '||v_role_name||' to '
                               ||v_user_name||'; '
                               ||' grant connect to '
                               ||v_user_name ;

Comment: execute it one by one and remove the semicolon (;) because execute immediate won't work then.